# Dynamically select element based on function parameter

Tags: c#, selenium, variables, testing, reference

I am creating an Automation Testing framework, and I came up with this function:

```
    public void DoClick(string selectType, string selector)
    {
        switch (selectType)
        {
            case "ClassName":
                driver.FindElement(By.ClassName(selector)).Click();
                break;
            case "CssSelector":
                driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(selector)).Click();
                break;
            case "Id":
                driver.FindElement(By.Id(selector)).Click();
                break;
        }
    }
```

I want to replace the "By..." with something like By[selectType], in order to write a single line of code, instead of the whole switch case. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple. There's really no need to do this. Why wrap a one-liner inside a function?

```
public void DoClick(By locator)
{
    driver.FindElement(locator).Click();
}
```